Tracking scalar quantities between GPU simulation steps
I have a CUDA simulation where collisions/contacts between clumps of spheres can occur. There may be many collisions (exceeding 15 million in any one step). Collisions between clumps are produced with a parallelized LBVH broad-phase and sphere contacts are then derived from these with a mid-phase/narrow-phase step.
Contacts are currently recorded at the sphere level. A sphere is uniquely described by a uint64_t tag, where the upper 32-bits are the clump index and the lower 32-bits are the sphere index inside the clump. Therefore, a contact is uniquely described by two uint64_ts or a single uint128_t, representing the two spheres that are actually contacting.
My problem is that I need to be able to match contacts from one simulation step to the next to accumulate specific values which are used to calculate forces, etc. I can not guarantee the order of thread execution on the GPU so I think I will have to sort the tag array such that contacts have a known/repeatable order.
I have attempted merging and sorting the two uint64_t tags using cub::SortPairs with a decomposer but this is simply too slow for my purposes.
Additionally, I have also investigated using spatial binning of the contact point (discretizing the simulation domain and clamping the contact point into a bin) instead of relying on the tag, however this is limited as the contact point may move outside of the bin between steps.
I think using a hash of the tag may be the best option, however I do not know what is best for this purpose.
I understand packing 128 bits into 64 will result in the potential for non-unique hashes, however I am willing to accept this possibility as it will likely be small for the number of contacts I am expecting, and will use further protective measures to filter hash collisions if necessary.
Is there a specific hash algorithm that is suitable for this purpose? Is there an alternative option for tracking quantities between GPU simulation steps (which is performant) that I have not considered?
Thank you very much in advance.
